# Statistical test for repeated measure data (3x2 contingency table)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, repeated-measures, wilcoxon-signed-rank

This is my dataset

```
           Newspaper    Internet
    MN     45           115
    IA     20           9
    MO     114          56
```

What statistical test should I use if my goal is to find find out if the numbers are statistically different between Newspaper and Internet group ? This is a repeated measure data.

I tried McNemar's test but it only works for 2x2 or square matrices does not work for a 3x2 table like this.
I tried wilcox.test that requires numeric data and not factors like (MN, IA, MO). Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried a chi-square test?

Comment: @DemetriPananos, can you use Chi-Square test for repeated measures ?

Comment: This is a pretty standard design for a chi square.

Comment: @DemetriPananos, My understanding is that ChiSquare tests are for categorical data where observations are indipendent and McNemar's-ChiSquare  test is for categorical repeated measure data. But McNemar's-ChiSquare  test only works on symmetrical design matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start pointwise

1. McNemar's test can't be used in this case. Had this been 2X2 and not 3X2, even then McNemar's test would have been wrong because it works on paired nominal data
2. Wilcox test is also referred for paired

One example of paired is pre-post i.e., earlier sample was not exposed to treatment (pre) and then sample was exposed to treatment (post)

This can be solved using Repeated measure ANOVA

```
from statsmodels.stats.anova import AnovaRM
import pandas as pd

df_anova = pd.DataFrame(data={'value':[45,20,114,115,9,56],
                  'y':['Newsp','Newsp','Newsp','Internet','Internet','Internet'],
                  'x':['MN','IA','MO','MN','IA','MO']})

av = AnovaRM(df_anova,depvar='value',subject='y',within=['x'])
av_res = av.fit()
print(av_res)
```

output ::

```
Anova
==============================
  F Value Num DF Den DF Pr > F
------------------------------
x  1.4766 2.0000 2.0000 0.4038
==============================
```

Hence, we fail to reject null hypothesis (that all groups are equal)...

Just a suggestion, it is always good to share your problem statement, give a brief description of your data, what you want to do and then come on things like "what test to use"

Comment: ha..for some reason i always thought ANOVA was used on data where the outcome was a continuous variable. Never thought we could use ANOVA for a count data like this. Hope this is not flagrant.

Comment: You are right @KimJenkins . I would put it in a way that ANOVA has an assumption that the data should follow normal distribution. I too assumed same..